# NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.api.scala.ScalaDsl.$init after scala/sbt ugrade

Tags: java, scala, cucumber, sbt, cucumber-jvm

I upgraded `Scala` from `2.11.8` to `2.12.4` and `sbt` from `0.13` to `1.4.6`, the project is compiling OK and running also but when I run `sbt test` it gives me below error.

```
 Test MyCucumberIT.initializationError failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.api.scala.ScalaDsl.$init$(Lcucumber/api/scala/ScalaDsl;)V, took 0.001 sec
[error]     at integrationtest.stepdefs.HttpStepDefs.<init>(HttpStepDefs.scala:12)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.scala.ScalaBackend$$anonfun$6.apply(ScalaBackend.scala:62)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.scala.ScalaBackend$$anonfun$6.apply(ScalaBackend.scala:62)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.scala.ScalaBackend.loadGlue(ScalaBackend.scala:62)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
[error]     at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
[error]     at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
[error]     ...
```

Below are the `plugin.sbt` and `build.sbt` respectively:

```
import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport.{assemblyMergeStrategy, assemblyOutputPath}
import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys

organization := "someOrg"
name := "someName"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val AkkaVersion = "2.6.13"
  val AkkaHttpVersion = "10.2.4"
  val dockerTestKitVersion = "0.9.3"
  val cucumberVersion = "1.2.6"

  val cucumberOrgId = "info.cukes"
  val akkaOrgId = "com.typesafe.akka"
  val slickOrgId = "com.typesafe.slick"

  val excludeLogBack = ExclusionRule(organization = "ch.qos.logback")

  Seq(
    akkaOrgId %% "akka-http" % AkkaHttpVersion,
    akkaOrgId %% "akka-http-spray-json" % AkkaHttpVersion,
    akkaOrgId %% "akka-slf4j" % AkkaVersion,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.39",
    "org.flywaydb" % "flyway-core" % "4.0.3",
    "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.5.1",
    slickOrgId %% "slick"          % "3.2.1" ,
    slickOrgId %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1",//
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
    "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0", 
    "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.1.0" excludeAll(
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scala-lang"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava")
    ),
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats" % "0.8.1",

    akkaOrgId %% "akka-http-testkit" % AkkaHttpVersion % "test",
    cucumberOrgId % "cucumber-junit" % cucumberVersion % "test" exclude("junit", "junit"),
    cucumberOrgId %% "cucumber-scala" % cucumberVersion % "test",
    cucumberOrgId % "cucumber-core" % cucumberVersion % "test",
    cucumberOrgId % "cucumber-jvm" % cucumberVersion % "test",
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test",
    "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.5" % "test",
    "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.2" % "test",
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test" exclude("org.hamcrest", "hamcrest-core"),
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test" excludeAll(
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scala-lang"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scala-lang.modules")
    ),
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.192" % "test",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % "test",
    "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.4.2" % "test",
    "com.whisk" %% "docker-testkit-scalatest" % dockerTestKitVersion % "test",
    "com.whisk" %% "docker-testkit-impl-docker-java" % dockerTestKitVersion % "test",
    // standard logging with ZipKin
    "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0",
    akkaOrgId %% "akka-stream" % AkkaVersion,
    akkaOrgId %% "akka-protobuf" % AkkaVersion,
  )
}

(testOptions in Test) += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/html-report")

val gitCommitString = SettingKey[String]("gitCommit")

gitCommitString := git.gitHeadCommit.value.getOrElse("Not Set")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAgent)
  .settings(
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](version, gitCommitString),
    buildInfoPackage := "buildInfo",
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToMap,
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToJson,
    releaseIgnoreUntrackedFiles := true,
    javaAgents += "io.kamon" % "kanela-agent" % "1.0.9" % "runtime"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last == "Log4j2Plugins.dat" => Log4j2MergeStrategy.plugincache
  case file =>
    val defaultStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    defaultStrategy(file)
}

assemblyOutputPath in assembly := file(target.value / "some" / name.value + ".jar")

test in assembly := {}

// Docker image generation and publishing to ECR

val currentBranch = Def.setting {
  git.gitCurrentBranch.value.replaceAll("/", "_")
}
val mainBranch = Def.setting {
  currentBranch.value match {
    case _@("develop"|"master") => true
    case _ => false
  }
}


import com.amazonaws.regions.{Region, Regions}

enablePlugins(EcrPlugin)

region in Ecr := Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)

repositoryName in Ecr := s"${organization.value}/${name.value}"

localDockerImage in Ecr := s"${(repositoryName in Ecr).value}:local"

repositoryTags in Ecr := {
  if(mainBranch.value) {
    Seq("latest", version.value)
  } else {
    Seq(currentBranch.value)
  }
}

push in Ecr := ((push in Ecr) dependsOn (createRepository in Ecr, login in Ecr, DockerKeys.docker)).value


enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

dockerfile in docker := {
  // The assembly task generates a fat JAR file
  val artifact: File = assembly.value
  val artifactTargetPath = s"/app/${artifact.name}"

  new Dockerfile {
    from("openjdk:8u131-jre-alpine")
    add(artifact, artifactTargetPath)
    entryPoint("java", "-jar", artifactTargetPath)
  }
}

buildOptions in docker := BuildOptions(cache = false)

imageNames in docker := Seq(ImageName((localDockerImage in Ecr).value))

// Custom release process

import ReleaseTransformations._

releaseCommitMessage := s"Setting version to ${(version in ThisBuild).value} [ci skip]"

releaseProcess := {
  if(mainBranch.value) {
    Seq[ReleaseStep](
      checkSnapshotDependencies,
      inquireVersions,
      runTest,
      setReleaseVersion,
      commitReleaseVersion,
      tagRelease,
      releaseStepTask(AssemblyKeys.assembly),
      releaseStepTask(push in Ecr),
      setNextVersion,
      commitNextVersion,
      pushChanges
    )
  } else {
    Seq[ReleaseStep](
      checkSnapshotDependencies,
      inquireVersions,
      runTest,
      releaseStepTask(push in Ecr)
    )
  }
}
resolvers ++= Seq(
  // someOrg resolvers
  "version99 Empty loggers" at "https://version99.qos.ch",
  Resolver.bintrayRepo("streetcontxt", "maven")
)

lazy val env = System.getenv()

credentials += Credentials(// some creds)
```

`plugin.sbt :`

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Flyway" at "https://flywaydb.org/repo"

resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "idio",
  url("https://dl.bintray.com/idio/sbt-plugins")
)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo("sbt", "sbt-plugin-releases")
resolvers += someOrgResolvers

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.9.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
//addSbtPlugin("org.idio" % "sbt-assembly-log4j2" % "0.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.7.0")
addSbtPlugin("se.marcuslonnberg" % "sbt-docker" % "1.4.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.mintbeans" % "sbt-ecr" % "0.9.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent"       % "0.1.6")
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt"  % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.9.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.waioeka.sbt" % "cucumber-plugin" % "0.2.1")
```

`build.properties`:

`sbt.version = 1.4.7`

I went through the top google links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175530/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-cucumber-api-cucumberoptions-snippets-while-running) and [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1087)

but didn't get anything useful.

**Update:**

As suggested by @m-p-korstanje, I changed the groupId to `io.cucumber` and version to `2.0.1`, it started the suites but now some suits are aborted with an error which is not making sense:

```
[error] Test suite someorg.api.route.VersionRoutesTest failed with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/testkit/package$TestDuration$.
[error] This may be due to the ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy (ScalaLibrary) used by your task.
[error] To improve performance and reduce memory, sbt attempts to cache the class loaders used to load the project dependencies.
[error] The project class files are loaded in a separate class loader that is created for each test run.
[error] The test class loader accesses the project dependency classes using the cached project dependency classloader.
[error] With this approach, class loading may fail under the following conditions:
[error]
[error]  * Dependencies use reflection to access classes in your project's classpath.
[error]    Java serialization/deserialization may cause this.
[error]  * An open package is accessed across layers. If the project's classes access or extend
[error]    jvm package private classes defined in a project dependency, it may cause an IllegalAccessError
[error]    because the jvm enforces package private at the classloader level.
[error]
[error] These issues, along with others that were not enumerated above, may be resolved by changing the class loader layering strategy.
[error] The Flat and ScalaLibrary strategies bundle the full project classpath in the same class loader.
[error] To use one of these strategies, set the  ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy key
[error] in your configuration, for example:
[error]
[error] set root / Test / classLoaderLayeringStrategy := ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.ScalaLibrary
[error] set root / Test / classLoaderLayeringStrategy := ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.Flat
[error]
[error] See ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.scala for the full list of options.
```

Comment: You should upgrade Cucumber. You've upgraded to 1.2.6 so your build tooling should inform you that the `groupId` has changed from `info.cukes` to `io.cucumber`. Change that and keep upgrading until you get to a recent version.

Comment: Thanks @m-p-korstanje that worked, I was able to initialize the cucumber using you.cucumber-2.0.1 but now I'm getting suite failures updated in the question